# Получение информации с 2 сайтов с помощью расширений

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как одним расширением собирать инфу с 2 сайтов одновременно?

У нас есть два новостных сайта, в которых новости добавляются с помощью WebSockets, после добавления мне нужно сразу же выводить их в моем расширении

Как это осуществить?

Comment: использовать request response

Comment: @Paulo Berezini Если можно участок кода, или ссылку на материал

Comment: это как бы самому надо писать участок кода, на то и профессия программист, чтобы придумывать как писать код

Comment: @Paulo Berezini а ссылочка на материал может где - то завалялась?)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp